# Docker Compose with static public IP over LAN but different with Host IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the requirement where I need to expose all my containers through a static public IP.
However, the static public IP cannot be host IP because host IP must be dynamic.

The 2 solutions I found is macvlan and linux secondary IP, but base on my understanding, they cannot fulfil my need.

with macvlan, each container will get individual IP. I need to access all container through the same IP.

with linux secondary IP, I can assign a single static IP which exclusive for my docker container. However, I didn't found a way to manage the `/etc/network/interface` inside a docker container.

My question is:

1. Is it possible to set all container using same ip using macvlan?
2. Is there any way to manage`/etc/network/interface`, include ifup and ifdown inside a docker container?
3. Is there any alternative method

Edit:
the image is the system design for what I wish to achieve:

[image: System design]

Answer (score 0):

Assign the static IP to your host and use the ordinary `docker run -p` option.  The host is allowed to have multiple IP addresses (it presumably already has its dynamic IP address and the Docker-internal 172.17.0.1 address) and you can use an additional parameter to `docker run -p 10.10.10.10:80:8888` to bind to a specific host address (that specific address and no other, port 80, forwards to port 8888 in the container).

Another good setup is to provision a load balancer of some sort, assign the static IP address to it, and have it forward to the host.  This is also helpful if you want to put some level of rate-limiting or basic HTTP filtering at this layer.

There's no specific technical barrier to running `ifconfig` by hand inside a container, but no off-the-shelf images expects to need to do it, which means you'll need to write all of your own images that won't really be reusable outside this specific environment.  A developer might have trouble running the identical image locally, for instance.

Comment: Just to clarify, basically your answer is similar to my second approach, and additionally bind the container to specific IP?

Comment: The containers don't know they're being NATted to a specific static IP address.

Comment: Understand, I've uploaded an image and I guess it same with the solution provided by you.